# How do I get my application to inherit the language a user selects in the install4j installer?

Tags: java, install4j

I've created a multi-language installer, using install4j.  All screens of the installer reflect the selected language, and my language .jar files are being created and put into a folder in the installation directory.  I'm having trouble bridging the gap between installer and application as far as language selection goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, call

```
String language = (String)Variables.getInstallerVariable("sys.languageId")
```

to get the language that was selected in the installer. To set this as your default locale, call

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale(language));
```

The `Variables` class above is in the JAR file resources/i4jruntime.jar, use this JAR file for compilation, but do no distribute it, it will automatically be on the class path.